# Internet of Things Cloud - Developer Edition

Tags: developer-org, iot

I am currently doing the trailhead module on IoT cloud and trying to access it throught the developer editon... I have trawled the web for this, but cannot find any resource. Is it currently available through a DEV account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe it is currently possible to access the IoT cloud in developer edition orgs - as at Spring '17.

I'm basing this on:

- Having never seen such a developer org to date
- That the [IoT Cloud Design and Rollout](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/iot_get_started_module) Trailhead module only has Q&A assessments rather than checks against an IoT enabled org. Trailhead would typically favor real tests over Q&A where possible. Especially for an advanced module.
- It's a paid feature that you need to access via your Account Executive, which a Developer Edition org doesn't have. Source - [Need access to IOT cloud demo org](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019TiiQAE)

Comment: Hi @DanielBallinger Are there any updates regarding this? Is there any way to get a trial version of IoT Cloud for 30 days? Any idea?

Comment: @SE_User I still haven't seen it in the wild or as something that developers can request access to directly. If you have a production org I'd suggest contacting your Account Executive for the next steps.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce IoT Explorer is now generally available as of W'18 and available in developer editions. I wrote two blog posts to help people get started and see how it fits into a larger IoT strategy:

- [Using IoT Explorer to Power Your Digital Transformation Projects](https://hub.appirio.com/tech-blog/using-iot-explorer-to-power-your-digital-transformation-projects)
- [Expanding Your IoT Explorer Prototype](https://hub.appirio.com/tech-blog/expanding-your-iot-explorer-prototype)

Comment: Careful not to be too overly promotional. These posts look relevant (at least according to their titles), so I won't take any action here. Just be careful to not have *all* of your answers link to your own blog posts. Your contributions will also be much more helpful and less spammy if you can cite some relevant content *here* so visiting the links is not strictly necessary to glean what useful information you are trying to provide.

Comment: Yeah, I hear that. It would take a lot of copy/paste to bring the content over here though. I could have provided a bit more info here on how to enable in W'18 orgs and then had a slightly seemingly promotional structure for my links. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: These posts are great - more information than I was able to find on any official Salesforce site.